# How to make Dynamic Charts label from Database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, charts

I wanted to make a dynamic Chart Bar where Label is every day of month and column value will be coming dynamically from database..
I have used [ConsoleTVs/Charts](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts) for making it.
I have products table with id , name,amount
I wanted to find total number of amount i have got perday based on products.Because same products can sell multiple time in a single day.
The problem with the below code is I'm getting no of products sell on each day not total amount. How do i represent it in chart bar

```
$data = DB::table('products')
                ->select('products.created_at',DB::raw('sum(products.amount) as sum' ))
                ->groupBy('products.id')                
                ->get();

        //dd($data);      
        $chart = Charts::create('area', 'highcharts')
            ->elementLabel("Total")
            ->title('Monthly Collection')
            ->dimensions(1000, 500)
            ->values($data->pluck('sum'))
            ->responsive(false)
            ->groupByDay();
```

Answer (score 0):

i have not got your question properly but i have tried this, let me hope it's of help

```
$data = DB::table('sales')
        ->join('products','sales.product_id','=','products.id')
        ->select('name', DB::raw('SUM(sales.price * sales.quantity) as total_sales'))
        ->groupBy('product_id')
        ->get();
    $chart = Charts::create('pie', 'highcharts')
        ->elementLabel("Total Sales")
        ->title('Sales Collection')
        ->dimensions(1000, 500)
        ->labels($data->pluck('name'))
        ->values($data->pluck('total_sales'))
        ->responsive(true);
return view('layouts.dashboard',['chart'=>$chart]);
```

i have a products table & sales table with product_id as foreign key in sales table.